# Modifying .page-content background image

Tags: pages

How can I implement it so that I switch per-post background images from the WP post-edit screen?

A developer helped me built a custom WP theme, but can't help me out right now. On this page:

http://vernisaj.ro/guetlinvelo/a-la-carte/litespeed/

there is a background image on the following CSS element:

```
.page-content { background-image: url('http://www.....' }
```

However in the WordPress editor, I can't seem to find this picture (I looked in all php files and css files, it's in there).

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: With the WordPress Editor I mean the one you'll get through Appearance -> Editor.

Comment: Your page gives me this... `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/kurator/public_html/guetlinvelo/wp-content/themes/guetlinvelo/page.php on line 3`

Comment: sorry, I tried solving it (didn't work), it should work now.

Comment: With "WP Editor" you mean the WordPress editor to change the content of a post/page or do you mean the editor to change template files (located in Appearance > Editor)?

Comment: Appearance > Editor!

Answer (score 1):

WordPress does not have such an option by default; you will have to create the functionality for per-post background images - which is entirely possible.

Your best bet might be to use **post custom meta** to link/upload per-post background images, and then enqueue a dynamic stylesheet that applies that image as the background for the post, using the `.postid-$id` CSS class.

1. Create a custom post meta box
2. Add to the meta box a form field to allow the user to provide a URL to an image, or to upload an image
3. Enqueue a function that queries the `post_custom_meta()`, and applies the background style if the appropriate post custom meta data exist.

**EDIT**

If you just want to know where that background image CSS definition is being applied: it is being **enqueued**, as a callback function likely to the *`wp_head`* or *`wp_print_styles`* action hook. You'll need to look in `functions.php` for this callback function.

Comment: Well I only want the page background to be changed and since it's only a seasonal change (when new bikes come in once a year) the picture shouldn't be updated all the time.

Comment: Okay, then can you clarify what you *really* want, because the CSS class you indicated is applied to the **Page** (i.e. Page post-type) content. If you simply want to be able to change it via CSS, then I don't really understand your question.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Yes I just want it for the page. I think you edited my question (I never wrote per-post), that's why there is a miscommunication :) Neither wp_head nor wp_print_styles can be found in the functions.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the CSS is actually pointing to an image on a different site: velo-service.ch

It's not hard to have a featured image for each post/page go to the background of that. But the page template needs to be coded that way.

Here's the relevant CSS as it is now.
    .page-content {
        background: url("http://www.velo-service.ch/htdocs/modules/content/litespeed.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    }

Comment: Yeah, but where would I put it? Overwriting .page-content { } etc. through the style.css doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress offers a simple solution for this question. If your theme is using the body_class.

**How it works:**
In the header.php file you should have <?php body_class(); ?>> This will give each page a unique ID. You then need a tool like the Firefox plugin Web Developer or Firebug to inspect the ID for the given page.

Comment: But I think he wants to be able to *define* the image to be used for a given post, *from* the post-edit screen for that post.